# Update value on Parse without fetching the object first (like SQL update)

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

Is it possible to update object's value without having to fetch the object first? I could save a bunch of Parse requests if this would work.

this is what I have now:

```
// this uses two Parse requests
PFQuery *q = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"conversations"];

// 1st request
[q getObjectInBackgroundWithId:_conversationID block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error){
    [object setValue:message forKey:@"lastMessage"];
    [object saveInBackground]; // 2nd request
}];
```

I want to do something like this:

```
// this would use one Parse request if it would work
PFQuery *q = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"conversations"];
[q whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:_conversationID]
[q setValue:message forKey:@"lastMessage"];
[q executeInBackground]; // the only request
```

I know executeInBackground doesn't exist but hopefully there is something else that I'm missing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Depending on your use case, you might be able to use cloud code.

Based on your code I'm guessing you want to add a chat message to a conversation. Instead of getting the conversation object and adding a message to it, and then save it, you could do this instead:

All chat messages get their own object. This means that when a user writes a message, this is one request: a new ChatMessage object including a property that is the conversation object. In the afterSave hook (cloud code), you could have a small script that gets the conversation object and adds a pointer to a pointer array in the conversation.

This lets you track all messages in a conversation, without doing all the queries on the device.